# How to delete rows that contain incorrectly formated date and time values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
df =
date        time   val1
1/17/2018   18:00  20.0
1/17/2018   18:02  21.1
1/17/2018   18:10  23.2
1/17/2018   18:12  22.0
17/1/2018   18:12  22.1
17-Jan-2018 18:12  22.0
1/18/2018   60     22.1
aa          17:30  23.3
17/1/20188  18:00  19.0
```

The condition to delete rows:

1. if the format of a field `date` does not correspond to '%d/%m/%Y'.
2. if the format of a field `time` does not correspond to "%H:%M".

Based on these two conditions the last 5 rows in `df` should be deleted to get a new clean dataframe.

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way `to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'` if the `format` not same as input , it will return `NaN`

```
s=pd.to_datetime(df.date+' '+df.time,format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',errors='coerce').notna()
df=df[s].copy()
df
Out[212]: 
        date   time  val1
0  1/17/2018  18:00  20.0
1  1/17/2018  18:02  21.1
2  1/17/2018  18:10  23.2
3  1/17/2018  18:12  22.0
```

Comment: What `df[s].copy()` does?

Comment: @Tatik https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Also check out the 3rd answer in that link ^

Comment: I got the error `TypeError: data type " " not understood`. I use python 3.

Comment: `s=pd.to_datetime(df.date+df.time,format='%m/%d/%Y%H:%M',errors='coerce').notna()` @Tatik

Comment: Now I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'datetime.time'`. I also cannot print variables in this way `print("val"+val)`. It says that `+` cannot be used. I don't understand why it happens.

Comment: `s=pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str)+df.time.astype(str),format='%m/%d/%Y%H:%M',errors='coerce').notna()` @Tatik